# E2037 error in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-10-seattle, synedit

I was trying to compile SynEdit code. Then I got several errors related to E2037 and E2065.

Here is the code. (The definition part of the code is thousands of lines long. I only pasted related lines here.)

```
TCustomSynEdit = class(TCustomControl)
  private   
    FAdditionalWordBreakChars: TSysCharSet;
    FAdditionalIdentChars: TSysCharSet;

    procedure SetAdditionalIdentChars(const Value: TSysCharSet);
    procedure SetAdditionalWordBreakChars(const Value: TSysCharSet);
  protected

  public
    property AdditionalIdentChars: TSysCharSet read FAdditionalIdentChars write SetAdditionalIdentChars;
    property AdditionalWordBreakChars: TSysCharSet read FAdditionalWordBreakChars write SetAdditionalWordBreakChars;
  published
    property Cursor default crIBeam;
  end;



procedure TCustomSynEdit.SetAdditionalIdentChars(const Value: TSysCharSet);
begin
  FAdditionalIdentChars := Value;
end;

procedure TCustomSynEdit.SetAdditionalWordBreakChars(const Value: TSysCharSet);
begin
  FAdditionalWordBreakChars := Value;
end;
```

I got the following errors:

```
[dcc32 Error] SynEdit.pas(8099): E2037 Declaration of 'SetAdditionalIdentChars' differs from previous declaration
[dcc32 Error] SynEdit.pas(8101): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'FAdditionalIdentChars'
[dcc32 Error] SynEdit.pas(8104): E2037 Declaration of 'SetAdditionalWordBreakChars' differs from previous declaration
[dcc32 Error] SynEdit.pas(8106): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'FAdditionalWordBreakChars'
[dcc32 Error] SynEdit.pas(828): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TCustomSynEdit.SetAdditionalIdentChars'
[dcc32 Error] SynEdit.pas(829): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TCustomSynEdit.SetAdditionalWordBreakChars'
```

I can't find any difference between previous and later declarations. I just don't get it.

Comment: It may be a compiler bug, but this error _can_ occur e.g. if you happen to have a unit in the `uses` list of the implementation section in which - in this case - `TSysCharSet` is redefined.

Comment: As a first you could try prefixing TSysCharSet with the full name space in all declarations - e.g. FAdditionalWordBreakChars: System.SysUtils.TSysCharSet

Comment: Fix your problem by getting the latest synedit

Answer (score 2):

1. Get latest version from [github](https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit), it supports XE8
2. Open source/SynEdit.inc file and add the following:

```
// this is existing lines
{ VERXXX to SYN_COMPILERX, SYN_DELPHIX and SYN_CPPBX mappings }
{---------------------------}
// begin of new block
{$IFDEF VER300}
  {$DEFINE SYN_COMPILER_22}
  {$DEFINE SYN_DELPHI}
  {$DEFINE SYN_DELPHI_XE8}
{$ENDIF}
// end of new block 
{$IFDEF VER290}
.......
```

3. Rebuild package.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is wonderful! I really forgot about it. Just a habit to install everything manually :)

Comment: Thanks! @DavidHeffernan After I asked this mail, I found your answer about GetIt. It is really helpful!!! Bail me out of these annoying compile errors.